# Creating a PostgreSQL connection with Entity Framework and Npgsql. Error is failing trying to read from SQL Server

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, npgsql

Attempting to create above connection via Entity Framework config file, and upon running get the following error :

> 13:02:57.058 0 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found

Seems to not be identifying that it is a PostgreSQL connection that I am trying to make.

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" 
                 type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
                 requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Test_Track" 
             connectionString="server=localhost;user id=rouser;password=pass;Database=track;" 
             providerName="Npgsql" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
        <providers> 
            <provider invariantName="Npgsql" 
                      type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql.EntityFramework" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" 
                 description=".Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" 
                 type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7"/>
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
```

- EF: Version 6.0
- VS .NET Framework 4.5
- Npgsql.2.2.7
- Npgsql.EntityFramework.2.2.7

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: What does the `SqlConnectionFactory` do? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.sqlconnectionfactory(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: https://gist.github.com/livioc/b3e9707354bf99f43c32

Comment: Which configuration file is the above from, as in from what assembly? Is this a web project or desktop/service? Make sure that these configuration sections are in the root site/application's web.config/app.config and not just a DLL's app.config. I don't believe the DbProviderFactories section is needed for connecting EF to PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2):

This error comes from the MS SQL Server Provider, not Npgsql.

The MSSQL Provider is trying to connect through Named Pipes which are a Windows only thing, not supported by Npgsql.

I would advise to review your configuration file and use Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionFactory instead of SqlConnectionFactory as the link provided by magicandre1981 shows.